# Sidekiq 6 only does polling when I enter web console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, systemd

I really don't know why but my sidekiq seems to stop working after a while.

However, if I

- open the web console `/sidekiq`
- login the server by ssh and `ps aux | grep sidekiq`
  once I do one of the above two things, `sidekiq` begin to poll immediately

My environment is

- Sidekiq 6.2.1
- Ubuntu20.04
- Rails 6.1.3.1

I use `systemd` and capistrano-sidekiq to control sidekiq, can anyone help me?

```yaml
# config/sidekiq.yaml
:queues:
  - default
  - order-jobs
```

This is the `~/.config/systemd/user/sidekiq.service` I write:

```sh
[Unit]
Description=sidekiq
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=notify
WatchdogSec=10

WorkingDirectory=/path/to/my/app/current

ExecStart=/home/my_username/.rvm/bin/rvm in /path/to/my/app/current do bundle exec sidekiq -e production
ExecReload=/usr/bin/kill -TSTP $MAINPID

# Greatly reduce Ruby memory fragmentation and heap usage
# https://www.mikeperham.com/2018/04/25/taming-rails-memory-bloat/
Environment=MALLOC_ARENA_MAX=2

# if we crash, restart
RestartSec=1
Restart=on-failure

# output goes to /var/log/syslog
StandardOutput=syslog
StandardError=syslog

# This will default to "bundler" if we don't specify it
SyslogIdentifier=sidekiq

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

Comment: How do you know it's not polling?

Comment: Those jobs are for exporting Excel files and then send email to users. I didn't receive the email after enqueueing jobs for a long time, maybe 6 hours. And when I enter `/sidekiq`, I found the queue has a lot of jobs. Currently, because it doesn't have too much data, so the exporting should not exceed 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user services of `systemd` turn out that they only live while the user has a login session.
The service will stop once the last session finishes.
So that's why my `sidekiq`, which is run by the user service, stops everytime after I logout.
we can simply use `loginctl enable-linger username` to create a continuing existing session of the user.